# Difference between key hash produced by x509 ocspid option and public key of the certificate

Tags: openssl

I am using Openssl Version: 1.1.1d

I was trying to debug a mismatch between Issuer key hash returned  by ocsp responder and the hash calculated on the public key retrieved from the certificate.

In order to check if everything was alright with the certificate, I executed the following commands:

1) **Retrieving Public key of the issuer certificate**

[Issuer public key command img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH260.jpg)

I used the command `x509 -in all_certs/cpo_sub_ca2_cert.pem -pubkey` and copied the public key field. I then converted the Base-64 key to Hex using [this](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) tool.
And then generated a sha1 hash for it.Following is the hash:

```
7f7d65e42a26021b69110e6a8f5d8638dfa7c565
```

2) **Retrieving hash of Public key of the issuer certificate that would be sent by ocsp responder**

I used the command `x509 -ocspid -in all_certs/cpo_sub_ca2_cert.pem` and got the following hash:

[Hash generated by ocspid option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3SO3.jpg)

```
Public key OCSP hash: D698940FD07B4AEB7DD08155B0C068BDB7A6A063
```

Why is there a mismatch between the two hashes ? I can confirm that the first hash is correct since that is exactly what i get on my client (which issued a certificate status request during TLS 1.2 handshake).Client uses WolfSSL in case you are wondering. Also this is exactly the mismatch that my client reports.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason. This happened because OCSP responder (here openssl) produced sha1 hash on uncompressed public key while the client that had received certificates from my server was calculating hash on compressed public key. Hence the hashes were different.

The fix for this issue (if it ever happens) would be to first decompress the key and then hash it, or compare hashes for both version of keys and then accept or reject an OCSP response from a given server.